# Perform a click on a curstom dialog

Tags: android, testing, dialog, click

I must test this dialog, but i don't get how i can click the second or another buttom from the code.

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"0", "1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"};
builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Please, express your opinion for this new Regular Path!");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) 
    {
        vote=item;
        dialog.cancel();
    }});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Comment: Are any of the answers working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the`getListView` method on the dialog, which retrieves the `ListView` which stores the choice items. Then you call

```
listView.performItemClick(
    listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null), position, position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give appium a shot? It's a free and great UI testing tool for apps (you can use it to simulate human actions (e.g. click on a button))

http://appium.io/index.html

Since it's integrated with selenium, to deal with alert dialog, just simply do

driver.switchTo().alert().accept();

Comment: As of today (2013-11-20) `driver.switchTo().alert()` is not yet implemented.